# React dnd kit sortable not able to sort items in canvas

Tags: reactjs, dnd-kit

I have a list of items that I am dropping into a canvas. But the items once they are added to canvas are not sorting. Here is my code. I am new to the dnd-kit, can someone help. Here is my sandbox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-lewin-68ut0l?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { DndContext, useDraggable, useDroppable } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import { CSS } from "@dnd-kit/utilities";
import { FiX } from "react-icons/fi";
import "./style.css";
import {
  SortableContext,
  useSortable,
  rectSortingStrategy,
  verticalListSortingStrategy,
  arrayMove,
} from "@dnd-kit/sortable";

const itemList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Item 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "Item 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "Item 3" },
  // Add more items here
];

const CanvasItem = ({ item, onRemoveItem, hideOnDrag }) => {
  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onRemoveItem(item.instanceId);
  };
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, isDragging } =
    useSortable({
      id: item.instanceId.toString(),
    });

  const style = {
    transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),
  };

  return (
    <div ref={setNodeRef} style={style} {...attributes} {...listeners}>
      <span>{item.name}</span>
      <button onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
        <FiX />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Canvas = ({ items, onRemoveItem, hideOnDrag }) => {
  return (
    <div className="canvas">
      <SortableContext
        items={items.map((item) => item.instanceId.toString())}
        strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
      >
        {items.map((item) => (
          <CanvasItem
            key={item.instanceId}
            item={item}
            onRemoveItem={onRemoveItem}
            hideOnDrag={hideOnDrag}
          />
        ))}
      </SortableContext>
    </div>
  );
};

const ItemList = ({ items }) => {
  const renderItem = (item) => {
    const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform } = useDraggable({
      id: item.id.toString(),
    });

    const style = {
      transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),
      cursor: "grab",
      border: "1px solid black",
      width: "100px",
      margin: "10px",
      padding: "2px",
    };

    const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
      <div
        ref={setNodeRef}
        style={style}
        {...attributes}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        {...listeners}
        className="item-list-item"
      >
        {item.name}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="item-list">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          {renderItem(item)}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Trash = () => {
  const { setNodeRef, isOver } = useDroppable({ id: "trash" });

  return (
    <div
      ref={setNodeRef}
      style={{
        width: "280px",
        height: "180px",
        backgroundColor: isOver ? "red" : "green",
      }}
    >
      TRASH
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [canvasItems, setCanvasItems] = useState([]);
  //console.log(canvasItems);
  const [draggedOverTrash, setDraggedOverTrash] = useState(false);

  const addItemToCanvas = (item) => {
    const newItem = { ...item, instanceId: Date.now() };
    setCanvasItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, newItem]);
  };

  const removeItemFromCanvas = (itemId) => {
    //console.log(itemId);
    setCanvasItems((prevItems) =>
      prevItems.filter((item) => item.instanceId !== Number(itemId))
    );
  };

  const handleDrop = (event) => {
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (over?.id === "trash")
      setCanvasItems((items) =>
        items.filter((item) => item.instanceId !== Number(active?.id))
      );
    else {
      const item = itemList.find(
        (item) => item.id.toString() === active?.id.toString()
      );

      if (item) {
        addItemToCanvas(item);
      }
    }
  };

  function handleDragOver(e) {
    const { active, over } = e;

    if (over == null) {
      return;
    }
  }

  const { isOver, setNodeRef } = useDroppable({
    onDrop: handleDrop,
  });

  const dropStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isOver ? "lightblue" : "transparent",
    minHeight: "300px", // Set the minimum height for the drop container
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <DndContext onDragEnd={handleDrop} onDragOver={handleDragOver}>
        <div className="side-by-side-container">
          <div className="item-list-container">
            <h2>Item List</h2>
            <ItemList items={itemList} />
          </div>

          <div className="trash-container">
            <h1>Trash</h1>
            <Trash items={itemList} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <h1>Canvas</h1>
        <div ref={setNodeRef} style={dropStyle} className="canvas-container">
          <Canvas
            items={canvasItems}
            onRemoveItem={removeItemFromCanvas}
            hideOnDrag={draggedOverTrash}
          />
        </div>
      </DndContext>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

// delete works but sorting doesnot
```

Comment: I made it work.. have updated the code in sandbox for anyone's benefit